# Timezone Changer PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a code which pulls a member of staffs timezone from a table ("timezones") this table has PHP friendly variables such as: "Europe / London"

I have been trying to set the timezone in my connection file (after the connection to the database) but it doesn't seem to be changing.

```
    $timezonechanger = $db->query(" SELECT * FROM `timezones` WHERE staffid='{$user->data['id']}'");
$timenum = $db->num( $timezonechanger );
$timechange = $db->assoc( $timezonechanger );
if($timenum==0){
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    putenv( "TZ=Europe/London" );
}else{
putenv( "TZ=$timechange[timezone]" );
date_default_timezone_set('$timechange[timezone]');
}
```

The above does not work but if I was to set the timezone to something like:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Midway');
```

Without pulling this through using data from the table it works fine.

I'm not sure what is going wrong and I have echod the table data to make sure that the information is definately being picked up...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Err... am having difficulty with what `num` and `assoc` are. For `num` you sure you didn't mean `num_rows`? And for `assoc` - `fetch_assoc`? Far as I know, `num()` and `assoc()` aren't PHP/MySQL core functions.

Comment: they do the same thing, I think that is PDO_MYSQL (the version I am using for queries etc.)

Comment: What do you mean "you think"? http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=num&scope=quickref - http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=assoc&scope=quickref not core functions. Unless you've got some custom functions.

Comment: I've only started recently working with this version of coding, I used to use the old MYSQL_FETCH_ARRAY() and MYSQL_NUM_ROWS() but we moved over to a new system which uses this form of querying which I have just recently got familiar with, anyway, the query isn't the problem, the timezone changing is.

Comment: FYI: `'$timechange[timezone]'` this is considered a literal string.

Comment: that string echos fine, but I can't seem to get the string to reflect with the correct timezone as per the value in the database.

Comment: But `echo '$timechange[timezone]';` would output `$timechange[timezone]` - which is why you can't get the string "to reflect." However `echo "$timechange[timezone]";` would give you very different results. What difference can you see between these two `echo` statements? Now look at `date_default_timezone_set('$timechange[timezone]')` - what do you think is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as you were passing a php variable in string and sometimes due to server settings it results in issues.

By the way using php variable without concating them with string is not a good habit.

```
$timezonechanger = $db->query(" SELECT * FROM `timezones` WHERE staffid='{$user->data['id']}'");
    $timenum = $db->num( $timezonechanger );
    $timechange = $db->assoc( $timezonechanger );
    if($timenum==0)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
        putenv( "TZ=Europe/London" );
    }
    else
    {
        $put_env = 'TZ='.$timechange['timezone'];
        $default_str = $timechange['timezone'];
        putenv($put_env);
        date_default_timezone_set($default_str);
    }
```

Let me know the feedback please.